# Como mezclar consultas SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

**series_trailers**:

```
ID EPISODEID  CONTENT  AUTHOR
-----------------------------
1  122383    url1     Peter
2  9999      url2     Ana
3  923822    stuff    Jhon
4  122384    url3     Drake
```

**series_episodes**:

```
ID      TITLE           SERIESID
--------------------------------
122383  Episode 1       23
9999    Somethingweird  87
923822  Randomtitle     52
122384  Episode 2       23
```

**series**:

```
ID   TITLE
-------------------
23   Stranger Things
87   Seriesname
512  Sometrashseries
```

Quiero obtener las últimas series actualizadas (con actualizadas me refiero a las últimas series a las que se les ha añadido un url para ver el trailer de un episodio). Cada URL en `series_trailers` está asociado a un episodio de `series_episodes` y cada episodio a `series`, si utilizo el siguiente código: `SELECT DISTINCT EPISODEID FROM series_trailers ORDER BY id DESC` obtendré lo siguiente:

- Stranger Things
- Seriesname
- Sometrashseries
- Stranger Things

Como podéis observar obtendría la serie Stranger Things dos veces, y eso es lo que no quiero. Sé que debe ser con un código sql que combine varios pero no estoy muy enterado en el tema, si alguien puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido :-)

Comment: Ismael, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías indicar por favor el manejador de Bases de Datos con el que estás trabajando? Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Existen al menos dos posibilidades para resolver esto.

### 1. Usando `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT s.TITLE FROM series_episodes se
INNER JOIN series s ON se.SERIESID = s.ID
INNER JOIN series_trailers st ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID 
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY se.ID DESC;
```

### 2. Usando `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.TITLE FROM series_episodes se
INNER JOIN series s ON se.SERIESID = s.ID
INNER JOIN series_trailers st ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID
ORDER BY se.ID DESC;
```

El resultado será siempre el mismo.

Viendo la tabla `series_trailers`, se comprende rápidamente que necesitas sacar de ella el nombre del autor, creando una tabla dedicada únicamente a los autores. De lo contrario, estarás obligado a repetir una columna `VARCHAR`varias veces. Y si se necesita conocer también ese dato para algunos informes, será mucho más complicado.

Veamos ahora algunas pruebas y sus resultados.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/EBF12669)**</kbd>

#### Tablas y datos introducidos para la prueba

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series_trailers 
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        EPISODEID INT,
        CONTENT VARCHAR(255),
        AUTHORID INT

    )ENGINE=INNODB;

    INSERT INTO series_trailers (EPISODEID,CONTENT,AUTHORID)
        VALUES 
        (122383,'url1',  1),
        (9999,  'url2',  2),
        (923822,'stuff', 3),
        (122384,'url3',  4)
    ;

   /*Puede que el ID de esta tabla sea auto-incremental*/ 
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series_episodes 
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        TITLE VARCHAR(255),
        SERIESID INT

    )ENGINE=INNODB;

    INSERT INTO series_episodes (ID,TITLE,SERIESID)
        VALUES 
        (122383,'Episode 1',23),
        (9999,  'Somethingweird',87),
        (923822,'Randomtitle',52),
        (122384,'Episode 2',23)
    ;


    /*Puede que el ID de esta tabla sea auto-incremental*/ 
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS series 
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
        TITLE VARCHAR(255)

    )ENGINE=INNODB;    

    INSERT INTO series (ID, TITLE)
        VALUES 
        (23,'Stranger Things'),
        (87,'Seriesname'),
        (512,'Sometrashseries') 
    ;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS authors 
    (
        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        AUTHOR VARCHAR(255)

    )ENGINE=INNODB;  

    INSERT INTO authors (AUTHOR)
        VALUES 
        ('Peter'),
        ('Anna'), 
        ('Jhon'),
        ('Drake') ;
```

#### Consultas de prueba

```
   -- Con GROUP BY
SELECT s.TITLE FROM series_episodes se
INNER JOIN series s ON se.SERIESID = s.ID
INNER JOIN series_trailers st ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID 
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY se.ID DESC;

  -- Con GROUP BY, incluyendo JOIN de AUTHORS
SELECT * FROM series_episodes se
INNER JOIN series s ON se.SERIESID = s.ID
INNER JOIN series_trailers st ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID 
INNER JOIN authors a ON a.ID=st.AUTHORID
GROUP BY s.ID
ORDER BY se.ID DESC;    

  -- Con DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT s.TITLE FROM series_episodes se
INNER JOIN series s ON se.SERIESID = s.ID
INNER JOIN series_trailers st ON se.ID = st.EPISODEID
ORDER BY se.ID DESC;
```

#### Resultados

```
-- Con GROUP BY

TITLE
Stranger Things
Seriesname

-- Con GROUP BY incluyendo JOIN de AUTHORS y todas las columnas

ID      TITLE           SERIESID    ID  TITLE               ID      EPISODEID   CONTENT     AUTHORID    ID  AUTHOR
122383  Episode 1       23          23  Stranger Things     1       122383      url1        1           1   Peter
9999    Somethingweird  87          87  Seriesname          2       9999        url2        2           2   Anna


-- Con DISTINCT

TITLE
Stranger Things
Seriesname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TITLE FROM series s LEFT JOIN series_episodies e ON s.id = e.seriesid LEFT JOIN series_trailer t on e.id = t.episodieid ORDER BY t.id DESC;
```

o quitas el distinct y haces un group by id, asi lo que haces es optener el titulo sin repetir